# Defcustom definition for plists

Tags: customize, defcustom, alists, plists

I want to write a `defcustom` definition for a variable `my-var`.

`my-var` is an alist that maps strings to plists.  Each such plists maps one of three keys (`:x`, `:y`, `:z`) to a list of strings.  So, a member of `my-var` could be:

```
'("key" . (:x '("a" "b") :y '("c") :z '("d")))
```

So I want the use to be able to provide a string to be a key of the `my-var` alist, and lists of strings as value for the three keys of the plist.

The problem is I don't know how to do that.  Specifically, I don't know where to put the `:option` keyword to offer `:x`, `:y` and `:z` as possible keys:

```
:type '(alist :key-type string
              :value-type (plist :key-type symbol
                                 :value-type (repeat string)))
```

Comment: Good question. Not enough good questions here about specifying types for `defcustom`, IMO.

Comment: Yeah, it's one of the very few cases with Emacs where I think the documentation could be a bit clearer/richer...

Comment: The doc could be better, but more importantly the Customize UI could be better. And the customize code is too complex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what you're describing:

```lisp
(defcustom myvar ()
  "..."
  :group 'mygroup
  :type '(alist :key-type string
                :value-type (plist :key-type symbol
                                   :options (:x :y :z)
                                   :value-type (repeat string))))
```

(You can also omit `:key-type symbol`, for the plist, as the type is symbol by default.)

I assume you don't really want to quote the values in the plist. That is, I assume that this is an alist element that you want to allow:

```lisp
("key1" :x ("a" "b") :z ("q"))
```

and not this:

```lisp
("key1" :x '("a" "b") :z '("q"))
```

aka not this:

```lisp
("key1" :x (quote ("a" "b")) :z (quote ("q")))
```

By the way, you can also use a `restricted-sexp` to specify that the plist keys must be keywords, not just any symbols.  Here's an example:

```lisp
(defcustom myvar '(("key1"))
  "..."
  :group 'emacs
  :type '(alist :key-type (string :tag "Alist key (string):")
            :value-type
        (plist :key-type
               (restricted-sexp :match-alternatives (keywordp)
                    :tag "Plist key (keyword)")
                       :options (:x :y :z)
                       :value-type (repeat string))))
```

However, I seem to have discovered a bug when you try to do that and also give it a `nil` default value.  I've filed Emacs bug #[59937](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=59937%5D) for that now.

Comment: Yes! Excellent, that's what I needed. And yes, the quotes shouldn't be there. Thank you!